# Rewrite this URL htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

How i can proceed for rewrite this url

```
http://mywebsite.local/videos?c=mycat
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.local/videos-mycat
```

Thx

Comment: By taking a look at any of the about 5638255826485 questions here on SO asking exactly the same that have been answered already. Why do you expect us to write the 5638255826486th answer just for you? What would be different?

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule    ^videos-mycat/?$    videos?c=mycat    [NC,L]
```

maybe...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^videos-([^/]*)$ /videos?c=$1 [L]
```